# как из update.callback_query.message.reply_markup вытащить нужные данные

Tags: telegram-bot

В боте телеграм я нажимаю на кнопку, мне нужно напечатать то, что написано на кнопке (на кнопке написано ФСК ЕЭС Б3).
по команде print (update.callback_query.message.reply_markup)
я получаю ответ
{'inline_keyboard': [[{'text': 'ФСК ЕЭС Б3', 'callback_data': '5'}]]}

если я пишу команду print (query.message.reply_markup.inline_keyboard)
то ответ [<****.***. object at 0x0000000004DCE630>] звездочки в ответе я написал, потому что на самом деле в ответе какая то ссылка на телеграм, и она при размещении здесь не отображается

а как же достать именно 'ФСК ЕЭС Б3'

Answer (score 0):

я пока достаю это название так
name_from_stroka = str(update.callback_query.message.reply_markup).split("'")
call=(name_from_stroka[5])

но предполагаю, что можно как то по другому, но не понимаю как